# hadoop - vertica jar

Tags: hadoop, jar, vertica

I am trying to transfer data from Vertica to hive. According to the manual the following should be set as the input format:

```
-inputformat com.vertica.hadoop.deprecated.VerticaStreamingInput
```

But the hadoop-vertica jar has  `org.apache.hadoop.vertica.VerticaStreamingInput` class and not the above.

So it is throwing me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
  class org.apache.hadoop.vertica.VerticaStreamingInput not
  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat
```

The full command is:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar \  
-libjars $HADOOP_HOME/lib/hadoop-vertica.jar \   
-Dmapred.vertica.hostnames=VerticaHost \  
-Dmapred.vertica.database=ExampleDB \  
-Dmapred.vertica.username=ExampleUser \  
-Dmapred.vertica.password=password123 \  
-Dmapred.vertica.port=5433 \  
-Dmapred.vertica.input.query="SELECT * FROM allTypes ORDER BY key" \   
-Dmapred.vertica.input.delimiter=, \   
-Dmapred.map.tasks=1 \  
 -inputformat com.vertica.hadoop.deprecated.VerticaStreamingInput \  
 -input /tmp/input -output /tmp/output -reducer /bin/cat -mapper /bin/cat
```

Hive is CDH-4.4.0-1.cdh4.4.0.p0.39/ environment and vertica is 7.1.

If I have the wrong hadoop-vertica jar, where can I get the correct one?  If that's not the problem, what am I doing wrong?

So where does this com.vertica.hadoop.deprecated.VerticaStreamingInput class come from? I got it from installing the Vertica connector.(Page 9 , step 5) https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/PDF/HP_Vertica_7.0.x_HadoopIntegration.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded the Hadoop Connector for MapReduce from [the downloads page on my.vertica.com](https://my.vertica.com/download-community-edition/#hadoop).  I took the 2.0 version (which supports CDH 4), since that's the Hadoop version you said you're using.

I looked in the hadoop-vertica.jar file in the downloaded file (yarn-vertica_1.6.0.zip) and it has the class file in the correct place (com.vertica.hadoop.deprecated).  The zip file also includes the source, so you can inspect it.

I can't tell where org.apache.hadoop.vertica.VerticaStreamingInput is coming from, but downloading a fresh copy of the connector should fix your problem.  Make sure download the JDBC driver and do the other Java configuration described in the documentation.